# Tensorflow-GPU running on python shell but not in jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to run tensorflow-gpu and it is working in python shell

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
...     print('Default GPU Device:{}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
... else:
...     print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

Output:
`Default GPU Device:/device:GPU:0`

But When I run the same code in Jupyter, I get this:

Output:
`Please install GPU version of TF`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSWtC.png

I am using Anaconda, I installed tensorflow-gpu using both conda installer and pip3/pip but does not work in jupyter. Anybody know what is wrong here? I have installed Cuda toolkit,cudnn, Nvidia drivers are also up to date.

Comment: When you couldn't get tf, are you then in the new conda jupyter environment?

Comment: What is the version of TF you are using? If it is installed properly it should work as expected. Can you create new environment and install required packages may solve your issue. Thanks!